# Nested pattern matching in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have following data structure to simulate alternative version numbering approach in Haskell:

```
data VersionNumber = VC (Maybe Int) -- VersionCompound: x (Nothing), 1 (Just 1), 2 (Just 2), 3 (Just 3), 4, 5, ...
        | VN VersionNumber (Maybe Int) -- VersionNumber: x.x, x.0, x.1, x.2, ... , 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, ... 1.x.x, 2.x.x, 3.x.x, ...
        deriving (Show)

versionCompoundToString :: (Maybe Int)-> String
versionCompoundToString (Just n) = (show n)
versionCompoundToString Nothing = "x"

versionNumberToString :: VersionNumber -> String
versionNumberToString (VN vn vc) = (versionNumberToString vn) ++ "." ++ (versionCompoundToString vc)
versionNumberToString (VC vc) = (versionCompoundToString vc)
```

Following constructs are legitimate given the above definition:

```
*VersionNumber> versionNumberToString (VN (VN (VC (Just 1)) Nothing) Nothing)
"1.x.x"

*VersionNumber> versionNumberToString (VN (VC (Just 2)) Nothing)
"2.x"

*VersionNumber> versionNumberToString (VN (VN (VN (VC Nothing) Nothing) (Just 3)) Nothing)
"x.x.3.x"
```

I am trying to write functions that would detect different version numbering patterns. For example, following function `isReleaseBranch` should return `True` for such version numbers as `1.x`, `x.2.x`, `x.x.3.x`, `x.x.x.x.5.x`, etc. Similarly, following values should return corresponding results: `x.x.4.x` -> `True`, `x.x` -> `False`, `1.2.x` -> `False`. What I could come up with so far is just following pattern matching implementation:

```
isReleaseBranch (VN (VC (Just _)) Nothing) = True
isReleaseBranch _ = False
```

I have no idea how to pattern match the nested pattern of arbitrary **x**'s on the left hand side of the version number: `VN (VC Nothing) Nothing` (`x.x`) of `(VN (VN (VN (VC Nothing) Nothing) (Just 3)) Nothing)` (`x.x.3.x`) or `VN (VN (VC Nothing) Nothing) Nothing` (`x.x.x`) of `VN (VN (VN (VN (VC Nothing) Nothing) Nothing) (Just 8)) Nothing` (`x.x.x.8.x`), etc. Is there any way to achieve such nested pattern matching in Haskell?

Comment: I can't completely understand, but if you want to handle arbitrary nestings, you have to use recursion. Your type is essentially a nonempty list of `Maybe Int`, so one can recurse on the list-like type.

Comment: I understand that I need to use recursion. But I have been thinking a lot on this problem and could not completely understand how it can be achieved even with recursion (if can be achieved at all)

Comment: What should the result be for 1) `x.x.4.x`, 2) `x.x`, 3) `1.2.x` ? I'm not sure what's the general rule. (Maybe you should add the expected result in the question itself)

Comment: `x.x.4.x` -> `True`, `x.x` -> `False`, `1.2.x` -> `False`

Comment: So, the general rule is: exactly one non-nothing number inside?

Comment: For `isReleaseBranch` yes, but there are other similar functions I didn't put into the question that use similar principle and require matching of arbitrary number of x's on the left hand side.

Comment: You're essentially trying to parse strings and decide whether they are in or out of your definition. I don't think the pattern-matching language is going to do anything magical for you here, you just have to write the parsing program.

Comment: You're aware that your type is essentially `[Maybe Int]` (well, `NonEmpty (Maybe Int)`)? That should give you some ideas.